# OCSP unknown status when passing cert, good status when passing serial

Tags: ssl, cryptography, openssl, certificate, ocsp

Okay, so I have a multi-layered ca system that looks like this:

-ROOT_CA

----intermediate_CA

--------intermediate_CA2

------------client certs...

I have an OCSP responder set up on intermediate_CA2 that is started like so:

```
$ openssl ocsp -index intermedia_ca_2_index.txt -CA ca_crt_chain.crt -rsigner intermedia_ca_2.crt     -rkey intermedia_ca_2.key -port xxxx -text
```

On the client side, I make an ocsp request like so:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer ca_crt_chain.crt -CAfile ca_crt_chain.crt -cert client.crt -text -host localhost:xxxx -verify_other... -trust_other
```

Note that client.crt is just the client cert, not the entire chain, though I have tried both ways and neither work. It always returns

```
Response verify OK
client.crt: unknown
```

If I change `-cert client.crt` to `-serial 0xXXXXXXXXX` (Obviously passing in a valid serial that cooresponds to client.crt) then everything works with:

```
Response verify OK
0xXXXXXXXXX: good
```

Oddly enough, if I examine the request in the first example, it is, indeed, sending the correct serial.

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought, but could it be that you also have to explicitly trust one of the certs in the chain on the server?

Comment: I am using multiple -verify_other options (one for each ca cert) and a -trust_other option.

Comment: Try changing the file you pass to `issuer` to only contain `intermediate_CA2` and not the entire chain.

Comment: That was, indeed, part of the solution. Apparently openssl ocsp isn't too fond of certificate chains.

Comment: Problem still persists in OpenSSL 1.1.1k. I created an issue in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18384.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution is that apparently openssl ocsp doesn't like chain files. So my server call looks like this now:

```
$ openssl ocsp -index intermedia_ca_2_index.txt -CA intermediate_ca_2.crt -rsigner intermedia_ca_2.crt -rkey intermedia_ca_2.key -port xxxx -text
```

Note that it would be more preferable to have an entirely seperate key pair for signing, but w/e.

The client connection would then look like so:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer intermediate_ca_2.crt -CApath /path/to/trust/store -cert client.crt -text -url http://localhost:xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed OpenSSL 1.1.1a (see [this commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/3bb0f989b53c59c6d4527a0b5077dbb7fabe14b7)).

This can be verified with the commands listed in [my issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18384#issuecomment-1195389145).